# Validating array inputs using jquery validation plugin -adding one error for first input

Tags: jquery, validation

```
 <form id="jvalidate" name="frmenquiry_package" class=""  action="#" method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="reg_number[]" id="reg_number_1" value="" class="jsrequired form-control" />
  <input type="text" name="reg_number[]"  id="reg_number_2" value="" class="jsrequired form-control"/>
  <input type="text" name="reg_number[]"  id="reg_number_3" value="" class="jsrequired form-control" />
   <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="button" id="submit"  onClick="javascript:funSave_contact_enquiry();">

   </form>






 function funSave_contact_enquiry(){

    if ($('#jvalidate').valid()) {
        $("#submit").attr('disabled',true);


    alert('Success');
    }
}




 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>site/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>site/js/additional.js"></script>
```

I have the following form. I am trying to validate the inputs using jquery validation plugin. I have tried some codes but its not working.

When i clicked adding one error for the first input #reg_number_1 only other fields not highlighted

Answer (score 0):

I made the 1st input only required for test, works fine with cdn :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function funSave_contact_enquiry(){
    if ($('#jvalidate').valid({rules : { reg_number_1 : "required"}})) {
        $("#submit").attr('disabled',true);
        alert('Success');
    } else {
        alert('fail');
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="jvalidate" name="frmenquiry_package" class=""  action="#" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="reg_number[]" id="reg_number_1" value="" class="jsrequired form-control" required/>
    <input type="text" name="reg_number[]"  id="reg_number_2" value="" class="jsrequired form-control"/>
    <input type="text" name="reg_number[]"  id="reg_number_3" value="" class="jsrequired form-control" />
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="button" id="submit"  onClick="javascript:funSave_contact_enquiry();">
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For Me also first input working but other two passes empty values

Comment: Sorry, missing the rules. I edit the post to add it.

Comment: For me reg_number[] will add dynamically

Comment: So add each rule dynamically.